# Non-linear matrix differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, matrix-calculus, nonlinear-system

I am facing the following non-linear matrix differential equation. $V$ is a symmetric $n\times n$ matrix, $u=(1,1, \dots,1) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ a row vector and $a$ is a constant.
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t}(t)=aV^2(t)\frac{u^{T}u}{uV^2(t)u^T}V^2(t) $$
In bra-ket notation :
$$ \frac{\mathrm{d}V}{\mathrm{d}t}(t)=a\frac{V^2(t)|u><u|V^2(t)}{<u|V^2(t)|u>}$$

I tried to use the diagonalization of $V$ : $V(t)=\sum_i\lambda_i(t)v_i^T(t)v_i(t)$ to get equations over $\lambda_i$ and $v_i$ but it doesn't seems to help...

I also tried to multiply the equation by $u$ on the right to get a differential equation on $w(t)=V(t)u$ :
$$\frac{\mathrm{d}w}{\mathrm{d}t}(t)=aV(t)w(t) $$
that is solvable by the ordered exponential:
$$w(t)=\mathcal{T}\lbrace \exp(\int_0^taV(t')\mathrm{d}t)\rbrace w(0) $$
But I don't think that introducing ordered exponential will simplify the problem.

As someone already faced such equation ? Is it solvable and do you have a clue to solve it ?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with bra-ket notation, so I might be misreading it, but (for the top expression to match the bottom) should the $u^T u$ term be $u u^T$ instead?

Comment: yeah I made a mistake that I edited : $u$ is a row vector, so that $u^Tu$ is the projection matrix on $u$

Comment: In that case, if $u$ is a row vector, I guess $u^T V^2(t) u$ should be $u V^2(t) u^T$?

Comment: Yes it is ! Sorry about that

Comment: Gotcha, no worries :)

Comment: A random thought: try solving for small $n$ first to see some pattern. For $n=1$ it seems to become $\dot V = aV^2$.

Comment: It might help to note that $uV^2(t)u^{\top}=\|V^2(t)\|_F^2$.

Comment: WalterJ : In fact $uV^2u^T=\sum_{i,j,k}v_{i,k}v_{k,j}$ doesn't seems to be a Frobenius norm